# Chaining function calls using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Hi Im trying to call subsequent functions of the same types passing parameters as shown in the example:

The problem is that im getting random output like, Line3, Line4, Line1, Line2. Am I doing something wrong with the chaining of is it a problem with the latency of the rendering of each text to screen? Should i use npm sleep?

```
var function1  = (senderID,req,FB_ID) => {

    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

        var line1 = 'Line1';
        var line2 = 'Line2';
        var line3 = 'Line3';
        var line4 = 'Line4';

        // Display lines of text
        sendTextMessage(senderID,line1)
          .then(sendTextMessage(senderID,line2))
          .then(sendTextMessage(senderID,line3))
          .then(sendTextMessage(senderID,line4))
          .then(resolve());
    });
};
```

Each sendTextMessage call calls this function below:

```
var sendTextMessage = (recipientId, messageText) => {

    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {    
        var messageData = {
            recipient: {
                id: recipientId
            },
            message: {
                text: messageText
            }
        };

        callSendAPI(messageData).then(function(){
            resolve();
        });
    });
};
```

CALLSENDAPI :

```
var callSendAPI = (messageData) => {
  var sleepSec = 1;
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

    request({   
        uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
        qs: { access_token: process.env.FB_PAGE_TOKEN },
        method: 'POST',
        json: messageData

    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          //var recipientId = body.recipient_id;
          //var messageId = body.message_id;
          sleep.sleep(sleepSec);
          resolve();

        } else {
         console.error("Unable to send message.");
         console.error(response);
         console.error(error);
         reject(error);
        }
    });
  });

}; // func
```

Comment: can I suggest, in `sendTextMessage`, remove the whole Promise constructor, and simply return `callSendAPI(messageData)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that what you have put as `then` argument gets executed immediately, while instead you should pass a function.

You could use `bind` to avoid overly verbose anonymous functions:

```
sendTextMessage(senderID,line1)
      .then(sendTextMessage.bind(null, senderID,line2))
      .then(sendTextMessage.bind(null, senderID,line3))
      .then(sendTextMessage.bind(null, senderID,line4))
      .then(resolve);
```

Also, note the `resolve` at the end, without parentheses: you want to *pass* that function, not *execute* it.